# Approach to Edit MS Access database with the same VB.NET 2010 standalone program on different computers

Tags: database, concurrency, ms-access-2007, vb.net-2010

I have an application in VB.NET 2010, and a MS Access database 2007 where I am able to edit (add, delete, update) registries with that standalone program that connects to it using Odbc.
The program needs to run in 2 computers, so 2 people would edit the database (maybe at the same time)...

Is it possible that somehow using the same program in both computers they can edit only one MS Access database?

I was thinking on a intranet or something to share the MS Access database file, but Is there a better approach? Is there any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an Access database from more than one computer, put it on a network share. Access handles the concurrent usage by way of the .ldb file. Only try this on a network that is very reliable, or you will run into database corruption, though.

Comment: So intead of adding the Access db in ODBC like ´Control Panel->Administrative tools->ODBC Data Origin´ what would be the way?

Comment: You can still use that method. But instead of specifying a local Access database (e.g., `C:\...`), you'd specify a database on your network (e.g., `\\server\files\database.mdb`).